# admob crashes my app

Tags: android, admob

can anyone please tell me what's wrong with this code?

```
package com.lightcone.simpledialer;

public class SimpleDialer extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private int entries = 6;
private String phoneNum[];
private String buttonLabels[];

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    phoneNum = new String[entries];
    buttonLabels = new String[entries];

    // Populate the data arrays
    populateArrays();

    // Set up buttons and attach click listeners

    Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setText(buttonLabels[0]);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setText(buttonLabels[1]);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button3.setText(buttonLabels[2]);
    button3.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    button4.setText(buttonLabels[3]);
    button4.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button button5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    button5.setText(buttonLabels[4]);
    button5.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button button6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
    button6.setText(buttonLabels[5]);
    button6.setOnClickListener(this);
}

// Launch the phone dialer

public void launchDialer(String number){
    String numberToDial = "tel:"+number;
     startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(numberToDial)));
}


/** Method to populate the data arrays */

public void populateArrays(){

    /** In a practical application the arrays phoneNum and buttonLabels could be 
     * updated dynamically from the Web in this method.  For this project we just 
     * hard-wire in some values to illustrate how to use such data, once obtained,
     * to make phone calls.*/

    phoneNum[0] = "000-000-0001";
    phoneNum[1] = "000-000-0002";
    phoneNum[2] = "000-000-0003";
    phoneNum[3] = "000-000-0004";
    phoneNum[4] = "000-000-0005";
    phoneNum[5] = "000-000-0006";

    buttonLabels[0] = "Jane D. Arc";
    buttonLabels[1] = "John Doe";
    buttonLabels[2] = "Jane Doe";
    buttonLabels[3] = "Abe Linking";
    buttonLabels[4] = "Mona Liza";
    buttonLabels[5] = "Issac Nuton";
}

/** Process button events */

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.button1:
            launchDialer(phoneNum[0]);
            break;

        case R.id.button2:
            launchDialer(phoneNum[1]);
            break;

        case R.id.button3:
            launchDialer(phoneNum[2]);
            break;

        case R.id.button4:
            launchDialer(phoneNum[3]);
            break;

        case R.id.button5:
            launchDialer(phoneNum[4]);
            break;

        case R.id.button6:
            launchDialer(phoneNum[5]);
            break;

    }
}

    public void onStart(){
             super.onStart();

             AdView layout = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);

             // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
             AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
             adRequest.setTesting(true);

             layout.loadAd(adRequest); 
}
```

}

and when i take off this

```
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();

    AdView layout = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);

    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    adRequest.setTesting(true);

    layout.loadAd(adRequest); 
}
```

the app launches great.
Thank you

here is the catlog

```
    07-12 03:27:41.485: D/AndroidRuntime(10744): Shutting down VM
07-12 03:27:41.485: W/dalvikvm(10744): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d560)
07-12 03:27:41.525: E/AndroidRuntime(10744): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-12 03:27:41.525: E/AndroidRuntime(10744): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.lightcone.simpledialer/com.lightcone.simpledialer.adMain}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lightcone.simpledialer.adMain in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.lightcone.simpledialer-2.apk]
07-12 03:27:41.525: E/AndroidRuntime(10744):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1581)
07-12 03:27:41.525: E/AndroidRuntime(10744):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
07-12 03:27:41.525: E/AndroidRuntime(10744):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
07-12 03:27:41.525: E/AndroidRuntime(10744):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
07-12 03:27:41.525: E/AndroidRuntime(10744):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-12 03:27:41.525: E/AndroidRuntime(10744):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-12 03:27:41.525: E/AndroidRuntime(10744):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
07-12 03:27:41.525: E/AndroidRuntime(10744):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-12 03:27:41.525: E/AndroidRuntime(10744):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-12 03:27:41.525: E/AndroidRuntime(10744):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
07-12 03:27:41.525: E/AndroidRuntime(10744):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
07-12 03:27:41.525: E/AndroidRuntime(10744):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-12 03:27:41.525: E/AndroidRuntime(10744): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lightcone.simpledialer.adMain in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.lightcone.simpledialer-2.apk]
07-12 03:27:41.525: E/AndroidRuntime(10744):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
07-12 03:27:41.525: E/AndroidRuntime(10744):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
07-12 03:27:41.525: E/AndroidRuntime(10744):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
07-12 03:27:41.525: E/AndroidRuntime(10744):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
07-12 03:27:41.525: E/AndroidRuntime(10744):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
07-12 03:27:41.525: E/AndroidRuntime(10744):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Since you didn't include the crash dump that Android generously provides in this situation, you make it difficult to know the real problem. However based on the small amount of code you seem to have isolated the problem to, I would speculate that either you have no R.id.adView in the actual content view you inflated, of you even inflated one, or rhe AdRequest method is returning null. Your crash log would tell you the exact line of the problem though.

Comment: post stacktrace from your logcat. Also, do you have internet permission in your manifest?

Comment: yes internet permission is on the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

You have ClassNotFoundException, and i think that because of missing activity declare in manifest. Also, move your code in onStart to onCreate, after setcontentview.

Comment: can you tell me how to do that please?

Comment: add this to your manifest, near other activity declare: <activity android:name=".adMain"/>, and add your code: 
    AdView layout = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    adRequest.setTesting(true);
    layout.loadAd(adRequest); 
after setContentView(R.layout.main); in onCreate.
Then remove onStart.

Comment: now the app opens, whithout crashing, the ads are showing, but the buttons dont work..